# git pull to merge into non-current branch for downstream repo to be able to track

Tags: git, git-pull

A remote repo has two branches `master` and `br1`. A local is cloned from it, and checked out on `master`.

With a `git pull origin br1:br1` command, it pulls remote `br1` into local `br1`, and merge down into the local `master` too. For example:

```
$ git pull origin br1:br1
   e73973c..9377c16  br1        -> br1
   e73973c..9377c16  br1        -> origin/br1
Updating cca5a9b..9377c16
Fast-forward  
 file2 | 0
 file4 | 0
 2 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

Basically three things happened: It brings remote `br1` into local `br1`. It brings remote `br1` into local `origin/br1`. Then it update local `master` with the same change set, that is revealed by the `Updating...` and `Fast-forward` messages.

Is there a command or some options to have it not to do the "updating current master" part?

I've read a few SO questions and answers. All of them suggest some sequence of commands or scripts. I wish that can be done in one single command, and further wish that command is not too complicated.

**Update**: With ideas from torek's explanation below, the answer is to use a non-standard setting:

Change the following two configurations in the downstream repo:

```
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.br1.merge=refs/heads/br1
```

to:

```
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.br1.merge=refs/remotes/origin/br1
```

Now, on the current repo with master as current branch, the command `git pull` will bring upstream changes from `br1` into `origin/br1`. Then a `git pull` on downstream repo will pull from `origin/br1`.

The normal `git push` command also works as usual on the current repo and the downstream repo.

Though this is not exactly merging into the non-current branch `br1`. But it works well for the purpose.

Comment: Why not just run `git fetch origin` (by itself) and then, if you wish to look at what has happened to `br1` on `origin`, use the updated `origin/br1` to identify the new commit history?

Comment: Hi, Torek, Can the further downstream track an `origin/origin/br1`? Is that a simple thing? Or any other simple ways?  Thanks to your help on the anther question.

Comment: Torek, As you mentioned earlier the `git-pull` is a script, if we want to make it not to do the 3rd action, where in the script source it should be modified? I did look at the source file, a bit too big to get an idea.

Comment: It is in fact possible to copy remote-tracking branch information.  It's not normally done and I am not sure if it's the "right way" but I'll add an answer below, along with what I suspect you may really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, you imply that the reason you want to have some particular clone be updated from an upstream, is that this clone is itself an upstream for further downstream clones.

There are at least two possibilities here, depending on what sort of results you really want.

The first is perhaps the simplest: you can make the initial clone a "mirror".  This action is supported directly by `git clone`:

```
$ git clone --mirror git://github.com/git/git
```

The `--mirror` flag implies `--bare`, so that the resulting clone is a bare repository, i.e., has no work-directory.  This is important because `--mirror` changes the default `fetch` refspec.

#### A standard clone

The *normal* (single) refspec for a clone whose remote is `origin` reads:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

In this case, running `git fetch origin` brings over all the branches from the upstream but renames them with the prefix `refs/remotes/origin/` (e.g., `refs/remotes/origin/master` and `refs/remotes/origin/br1`).

#### A mirror clone

In a mirror clone, however, the refspec in the git configuration file will read:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/*:refs/*
```

This means that running `git fetch` will bring over branches like `refs/heads/master` and `refs/heads/br1`, but when it does so, it will update local references `refs/heads/master` and `refs/heads/br1`.

The result is that local changes to this repository are wiped out: the repository's branch contents are replaced with a new "mirror image" of the repository's upstream.  (The term "mirror image" might be a bit misleading, since people looking in a mirror interpret the results as left/right reversed.)  Since the refspec source-side matches `refs/*`, any tags and notes are similarly replaced as as well.

(Besides the `fetch` refspec change, `remote.mirror` is set to `true`; I'm not sure off-hand what inspects this.  You might want to set `remote.origin.prune` to `true` as well, and/or set `fetch.prune`, so that branches, tags, and other references that have been deleted upstream are automatically deleted on `fetch` or `git remote update` operations.)

**The main function of a mirror is generally to act as a single point-of-reference for a group.**  For instance, if you have a company policy of keeping a copy of the git tree for `git` available, you might want to have a formal company-wide mirror, so that everyone within the company can update their personal copy of the git sources from the mirror, with the mirror itself updated periodically from the github version.

(This is particularly useful when a large sub-group is behind a slow network link: instead of dozens of users copying from a difficult-to-reach upstream, you have one user copying to a re-distribution point, and then everyone copies from there.)

#### A very non-standard mirror method

The problem with a pure mirror of this sort is that it is (necessarily) a `--bare` clone, so no one can work on it.  If what you want is a regular clone that can be re-cloned without having to "look upstream twice", however, you can do that.

In particular, suppose you make an initial clone of some project:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/some/project
```

and then create a (local) branch within this clone that is not in the upstream project:

```
$ git checkout -b xyzzy origin/master
... work and make commits ...
```

You now have a copy of the upstream project that is not a pure mirror: it has its own added biological and technological distinctiveness, in the `xyzzy` branch.

Suppose also that, for whatever reason, you wish to clone this clone, but be able to "see" updates to the original project *only when they are added to this clone* by an ordinary `git fetch`.

It's difficult to talk about all these clones without giving each one a unique name.<sup>1</sup>  Let's call the original project Alpha, the first clone Beta, and the second clone Gamma.

If, from Gamma, you run `git ls-remote origin`, you will see `refs/heads/xyzzy`, `refs/heads/master`, and `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  The point here is that *Gamma can see Beta's remote-tracking branches.*

If, from Gamma, you run:

```
$ git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch
```

you will see that it has just the usual standard `fetch =` line:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

What this means is that running `git fetch` on Gamma *discards* all the `refs/remotes/` remote-tracking branches it sees.  Gamma copies Beta's `refs/heads/` branches to Gamma's `refs/remotes/origin/` name-space, but throws away Beta's `refs/remotes/origin/` entries.  This is reasonable enough: where would Gamma put these?  They cannot go in Gamma's `refs/remotes/origin/` name-space.  You, however, can invent *your own* name-space, or borrow the remote-tracking name-space.

Suppose you were to add a second `fetch` line:

```
$ git config --add remote.origin.fetch '+refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/remotes/o2/*'
```

Now if you run `git fetch` on Gamma, Gamma will contact Beta as usual, obtain the complete list of references, and copy branches like `master` and `xyzzy` to `refs/remotes/origin/master` and `refs/remotes/origin/xyzzy` as usual—but it will *also* copy Beta's remote-tracking branches.  In this case, it will copy Beta's `refs/remotes/origin/master` to Gamma's remote-tracking branch named `refs/remotes/o2/master`.

#### A much simpler alternative

While you certainly *can* do the above on Gamma, you can also do something quite a bit simpler: on Gamma, you can add Alpha as a new remote:

```
$ git remote add alpha git://github.com/some/project
```

If you examine the new remote's configuration, you will see this:

```
[remote "alpha"]
    url = git://github.com/some/project
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/alpha/*
```

Now, in Gamma, you can simply run `git fetch alpha`.  Gamma's git will contact Alpha directly and obtain its branches as usual.  These will get remote-tracking branches named `alpha/master`, `alpha/br1`, and the like.

This simpler alternative is, well, simpler, and probably best, unless you have the kind of constraints that lead people to use mirrors.  In that case, it's still probably simplest to have a mirror clone, and then have ordinary clones: the mirror takes the place of the original upstream called Alpha above, and then the two clones of the mirror are Beta and Gamma respectively.  They no longer follow each other, they only follow Alpha, but Alpha follows the github (or other sharing-site) upstream.

---

<sup>1</sup>But please let's resist the temptation to use names like "Seven of Nine" :-)

Comment: Torek, Maybe another non-standard mirror. I changed to `fetch = +refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`. Now a `git fetch` would just bring in all the changes into `remotes/origin/*`. One thing though, on `br1` if I run `git rebase` the local `br1` won't fast-forward. It did before. Had to run `git merge origin/br1`. Any idea why?

Comment: Ok, also changed `branch.br1.merge=refs/remotes/origin/br1`, now everything works. The previous change is `remote.origin.fetch=+refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.

Comment: The `fetch = +refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` will work, but it means that Gamma simply copies Beta's copies of Alpha, and never copies Beta's branches anywhere.  If you're OK with that, it's fine.  As for the `branch.br1.merge` line, that one is weird: are you setting that on Beta, or on Gamma?  [Oh, I see in the question update, that's on Gamma.  That probably will work as desired, yes.]

Comment: If there are any changes in Beta I would push to Alpha and pull back. Thus Gamma will be up to date. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The `git pull` command effectively combines `git fetch` and `git merge` *.

You should use `git fetch origin` and then `git checkout br1` if it's not already the current branch, and merge the remote tracking branch with `git merge origin/br1`.

(* actually instead of `git merge`, `git pull` will perform like `git rebase` depending on options, when local and remote have diverged.)

Comment: I'm looking for a simpler approach, best one command without scripting.

Comment: Well, editing an existing script is ok, if the change is not too complicated.